# Sistema de formulário pela data base como pegar dados no $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

omo formatar

► coloque retornos entre os parágrafos

► para quebra de linha adicione 2 espaços no final

► *itálico* ou **negrito**

► recue o código em 4 espaços

► escapes de acentos graves `parecido _portanto_`

► destaque colocando > no início da linha

► para fazer links

http://foo.com
[foo](http://foo.com)
[foo](http://foo.com)

► HTML básico também é permitido

ajuda na format

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['nome']))
{
   foreach($_POST['nome'] as $key => $value)
   {
       echo 'Nome: '.$value;
       echo '<hr/>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Olá! Como posso inserir isto na data base, digo no INSERT coloco, o $value?

Comment: Eu coloquei aqui no insert e não inseriu nada na data base, como se ese código estivesse bloqueando o insert, clico no botao de "enviar" a página atualizada mas não acontece nada. Já tentei muda o if (isset($_POST['nome'])) com outro nome no formulário mas não insere nada na data base :(

Comment: @devmacedo podes explicar o código que colocaste na resposta? clica em [edit] para juntar isso à resposta

Comment: @CarlosGomes Por favor não altere a pergunta em função das respostas, senão as respostas já existentes (esta, no caso) perdem o sentido. Vamos esperar o devmacedo voltar e complementar a resposta. Se isso não resolver sua dúvida, você pode postar outra pergunta com base na nova situação. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Testei seu código com update segue como ficaria para funcionar:

```
   <code>
       <?php   
        require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); 
        if (isset($_POST['acao'])) {
            if (isset($_POST['nome'])) {
                reset($_POST['nome']); 
                while (list($key, $val) = each($_POST['nome'])) {  
                      //echo "$key => $val\n";  
                      mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
                      $gostou = mysql_query("update tab_statusoperacao SET DESCRICAO = '$val' WHERE CODSTATUSOPERACAO = '$key' ");

                }
            }
        }
        ?>

        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-bottom:5px"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="acao" id="acao" value="1" /> 
            <?php
            mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
            $get_form = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tab_statusoperacao") or die(mysql_error());
            while ($form = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_form)) { ?>
              <p>
                <label class="label-form" for="<?php echo $form['CODSTATUSOPERACAO']; ?>"><?php echo $form['DESCRICAO']; ?></label>
                <br />      
                <input type="text" name="nome[<?php echo $form['CODSTATUSOPERACAO']; ?>]" id="<?php echo $form['CODSTATUSOPERACAO']; ?>" class="input-form" value="<?php echo $form['DESCRICAO'];?>" />
                <br />  
              </p>
            <?php } ?>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar2" class="input-form" value="Enviar" />
        </form> 
    </code>
```

Comment: no name do input passei o id para recuperar no post e fazer o update

Comment: Olá! Testei aqui e não obtive resultados, não é inserido nada na data base, testei com INSERT.

Comment: E seria possível recuperar no POST somente assim? name="<?php echo $form['CODSTATUSOPERACAO']; ?>" Seria muito massa!

Comment: Em relação à não funcionar com o insert pode ser alguma coisa que você esqueceu no seu código esse que postei passa o valor para o post correto, em relação a recuperar no POST somente com name="<?php echo $form['CODSTATUSOPERACAO']; ?>" é possível sim, desde que os post seja validado, eu já fiz um sistema que montava campos através da base, porém o meu post só tinha campos que eu iria usar na base exemplo o hidden acao não...teria que validar e desconsiderar ele aí não colocaria while (list($key, $val) = each($_POST['nome'])) {  e sim while (list ($key, $val) = each ($_POST)) {

Comment: E para não usar o nome no name o if relacionado a ele não existiria if (isset($_POST['nome'])) { nem o reset com esse post

Comment: Solange, então o if (isset($_POST['nome'])) { ficaria assim  if (isset($_POST)) {  ou não teria esse Post somente apartir do while (list ($key, $val) = each ($_POST)){

Comment: Solange, fiz como você disse e refiz o código do formulario funcionou direitinho, obrigado. Você sabe como faço pra verificar se os campos q estão em obrigatorio na data base funcionem? Exemplo o campo foto é obrigato mais o campo email não é, ai verificar se preencheu somente o campo foto q é obrigatorio só q além dos campos serem pela data base esse obrigatório também é. É dificil de explicar rsrs mais sabe como posso fazer?

Comment: Bom se eu entendi direito coloque o if por exemplo no input: <?php if($form['obrigatorio'] == 'sim'){ ?>required="required"<?php } ?> ...agora se for a validação na hora de realizar a inclusão na base, lá na hora de dar o insert, poderia passar por um hidden, mas se você fez sem a variável com o nome no name aí já iria aumentar o trabalho em relação a ignorar esse hidden, talvez um select antes do insert seria mais viável

Comment: Eu usei o required e olha com certeza é mais facil kk, é possível eu colocar uma mensagem personalizada no required? Um alert script? A ULTTIMA COISA kk, é possível eu colocar um formulario de enviar imagem um tipo file mais q so aceite Imagem, no caso ia inserir a imgem em uma pasta do servidor e inserir o link na data base junto com os formulários, me diga q sim e q o código seja simples, e mais uma vez muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Comment: Sim é possível mensagem personalizada no required usando css ou um jquery tem vários modelos na net dá uma pesquisada com vários css diferentes e tal, em relação ao campo file sim é possível você pode validar formato do arquivo por javascript ou php mesmo, eu prefiro por php, também tem bastante material na internet sobre isso.